# Reconstruction of tensor in sktensor/scikit-tensor after decomposition using HOSVD

Tags: python, tensor, scikit-tensor

I am currently factorizing a 3-D tensor like [user,item,tags]=rating. I am using sktensor library in python for decomposition. For ex.

```
T = np.zeros((3, 4, 2))
T[:, :, 0] = [[ 1,  4,  7, 10], [ 2,  5,  8, 11], [3,  6,  9, 12]]
T[:, :, 1] = [[13, 16, 19, 22], [14, 17, 20, 23], [15, 18, 21, 24]]
T = dtensor(T) 
Y = hooi(T, [2, 3, 1], init='nvecs')
```

Now what is actually function hooi is returning and how to reconstruct the tensor from that ???

Comment: Late answer but I covered all your questions

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the function `tucker_hooi` computes the Tucker decomposition of a tensor using Higher-Order Orthogonal
    Iterations.

---

The function is the following:

```
hooi(X, rank, init)
```

where:

- `X` is the tensor to be decomposed
- `rank` is the rank of the decomposition for each mode of the tensor
- `init: {'random', 'nvecs'}` is the initialization method to use (random or HOSVD)

---

**Example:**

```
from sktensor.tucker import hooi
import numpy as np
from sktensor import dtensor

T = np.zeros((3, 4, 2))
T[:, :, 0] = [[ 1,  4,  7, 10], [ 2,  5,  8, 11], [3,  6,  9, 12]]
T[:, :, 1] = [[13, 16, 19, 22], [14, 17, 20, 23], [15, 18, 21, 24]]
T = dtensor(T) 
print(T.shape)
#(3, 4, 2)

Y = hooi(T, [2, 3, 1], init='nvecs')

core_S = Y[0]
core_S = np.array(core_S)
print(core_S.shape)
#(2, 3, 1)

U1 = Y[1][0]
U2 = Y[1][1]
U3 = Y[1][2]

print(U1)

[[ 0.54043979  0.7357025 ]
 [ 0.57659506  0.02952065]
 [ 0.61275033 -0.67666119]]
```

---

### Interpretation of results

- `core_S` is the core tensor S
- `Ux` is the left singular matrix Ux for the mode x

---

### Visualization

[image]

---

### **EDIT 1:**

To reconstruct the original tensor T do this:

```
from sktensor.core import ttm

core, U = hooi(T,rank= [2, 3, 1])
Trec = ttm(core, U)

print(Trec.shape)
#(3, 4, 2)
```

Source: https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor/blob/master/sktensor/tests/test_tucker_hooi.py

Comment: Good explanations for Tucker decomposition. What about CP-decomposition? Is there an efficient solution for a very large and sparse tensor? Thanks.

Comment: @seralouk So to go back to my tensor `T` from its decomposed form I should do `T = core_S.dot(U1).dot(U2).dot(U3)`. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm missing something? Thanks!

Comment: How do you decide the rank as [2, 3, 1]? Is there any specific method to do that? I came across *Percentage of Variance Explained* that decides to select the rank. Is there any way to implement this?